How do I minimize aerophagia while biking?
I often have serious problems with aerophagia (swallowing air) while biking. It's extremely painful and stupidly annoying. I've narrowed down the causes to two that seem significant.

drinking from a hydration tube while biking (I have a 1/2 gallon bottle in my triangle with a tube on it, and no interest in going back to normal bottles)

breathing too hard to swallow at all without swallowing air (Mayo Clinic's website says aerophagia during exercise indicates the routine is too strenuous, but I don't believe that)


The problem seems to be particularly bad when these factors coincide; riding hard on a hot day results in me trying to drink water while breathing too hard and by the time I get home my stomache hurts like hell. Then I have to spend 30-40 minutes hopping around, doing jumping jacks, lunges, side-bends, and massaging my abdomen while basically burping continuously to make the sharp, intense pain go away.
I've tried a few of the tips online like only breathing in thru my nose and only taking small sips of water. They might help a bit but so far the only way I've found to prevent aerophagia completely is to simply not drink water if I'm breathing at all. That means no water until I take a break long enough for my breathing to slow to the point where I can hold my breath. So I get dehydrated on every ride.
I'm not a time trial racer, or any kind of racer actually. I just bike for fun and you'll never convince me that I breath harder than a pro cyclist during a race. So I don't know why I have this problem.
Has anyone else had a problem like this or perhaps encountered a way to prevent it?
{EDIT: since some answers discuss types of bottles/hydration solutions here's a pic of my current setup. Before that it was a milk jug in a backpack. I had to stop to drink and simply didn't do it often enough}


Why not plan regular stops to get your breath and drink?

What's the temperature of your water?  I wonder if really-cold liquid would help, carrying a vaccuum flask of ice water instead ?

Also, - is it just water or are you drinking something wiht electrolytes/flavour etc.

The bottle is a Camelbak vacuum insulated 64 oz (barely fits in the Bikase ABC cage) and I fill it with plain refrigerated water. It's not ice-cold but still pretty cool after a 3-4 hour ride, if it's not gone.

Taking breaks would probably help a lot but I don't like stopping. For me it's easier to just push thru a 3-4 hour ride with no breaks. I pick up trash, move roadkill off the pavement, and on rides exceeding 2 hours, stop in the middle to do carpel tunnel exercises, but I never just stop and rest unless the ride is about 5 hours or longer (which is rare). So I have to choose between dehydration or making stops long enough to catch my breath so I can safely drink water. I don't like either option.

Judging by your description, seeking professional medical advice may be your best bet.

How can you swallow air with a mouth full of water? Maybe the drinking bladder is making it worse since you actively have to suckle? With a bottle you squeeze the water into your mouth with your hands.

@Michael I've wondered the same thing and it appears that it's not air in the water/tube but rather air and water mixing in my mouth because I haven't fully stopped breathing while I take a drink and also because my setup requires so much suction that I might also be sucking air in around the mouthpiece.

@MaplePanda If I can't find a solution online I do plan to ask my doctor for some kind of referral to a specialist who might know how to prevent this problem.

I drink a glass of water 15 minutes before a ride.
I only drink from a bottle and then only drink a small mouth full of water while on the saddle, every 30 minutes, at the most a small mouth full.
The dry mouth feeling that may temp me to drink more, I ignore other wise I would be drinking too much and have to stop to pass water sooner than later.

@MindDBike that's fine for short rides, but for longer rides drinking to thirst is a sensible minimum - and thirst includes a dry mouth.

It really is worth trying bottles even if only as a test, or at least a bladder that's not so low. You're bound to get some air out of the hose with that setup. Small sips will make it worse as you'll end up taking more of them.

On this morning's ride I tried the strategy of drinking tons of water whenever I wasn't breathing hard and then not drinking at all other than that. It seemed to work great, no dry mouth and no swallowed air, but it was also pretty humid and my ride was only 2 hours due to weather (I normally do 3-4 min). It's a promising development tho and I intend to try that strategy again.

I think the same as you about small sips, that they make more opportunity for air to enter, but medical sites say to take small sips to minimize air swallowing. I'm sure they say that for a reason but I don't totally understand it.

To my experience, the hydration tube is clearly an aggravating factor.
I started using one recently when riding in group/peloton. I'm new to tight group riding and not very confident in staying in the group while drinking. Drinking only during the stops was not a compromise that I considered acceptable (especially in summer). Not drinking also because it impacted performance, not in the racing sense, but when you struggle where you shouldn't, it's not enjoyable either — it's of course more visible in paced group rides than when riding alone. So I bought one of these jerseys with a pocket for an hydration bladder - the bladder is located between the shoulder blades so require less suction than a bottle placed on the frame.
Drinking from the tube seems to be an acquired skill, as I ended up with stomach pains in the first rides, but didn't make a link with aerophagia until I read your question, but because of the suction required, it's clear that drinking must be done when the effort is lowest — downhill (not the beginning though as you may not have caught your breath) seems the best moment, flat terrain can require as much power as uphill if you need to maintain some speed. I don't have such pain when drinking from bottles, for what it's worth.
That being said, from reading your question, it looks like you already know an approach to minimize the problem: to stop to drink. A point to improve is maybe the drinking technique: since you stop, you can for example open the bottle cap and drink like you'd do from a glass, which would allow to swallow larger quantities at once (and lower the amount of time you need to hold your breath when drinking).
Just a note: I understand the preference of not stopping when riding, but I fail to understand how it can be put at the "same level" as dehydration or 40min of "recuperation" after a ride. Stopping can also be nice to enjoy the landscape, and discover stuff that you can't see when riding, and if you don't race there's no other implication than a "small concession", which can't be said for dehydration and the "recuperation". It may not even be an overall concession on the ride, as correct hydration may allow you to catch up the time lost either a lowered performance or when stopping (not speaking about the long term consequences of regular dehydration).

I didn't know they made jerseys that could hold a hydration bladder, that's pretty cool. Do you still end up with a big hot sweaty patch on your back like with a normal hydration pack tho? I assume the volume and weight are lower but is the jersey tight enough not to flop side-to-side when you pedal standing up?

I did 60 miles this morning. On one of my stops when I wasn't breathing hard at all I took a handful of long hard gulps from the tube, as a test, and then started riding again. A minute later I thought "I'm fine, I guess it only happens when I'm breathing hard" but then two minutes after that I belched enough to fill a jumping castle. So the hydration setup is definitely part of the problem. I have to drink more gently and slowly because hard fast gulps pull in air around the mouthpiece and possibly also down my nose and up my trachea.

"when effort is lowest" is a tough one for me. I'm on the edge of the Great Plains near the Colorado-Nebraska border. Today's ride involved a steady 200 foot climb over 30 miles of dead straight highway. The wind can be huge out here but I tend to just ride faster or slower at the same exertion level. It's hard to find reasons to stop; shade is extremely rare. Even when I pee I just put my feet down, pee on the pavement and hop back on without ever stepping off the bike. There's so little traffic that I usually don't even have to wait for a break so no one sees.

@user66598 It's the Castelli Unlimited Pro jersey, the biggest bladder that fits is the 1.5l from EVOC (the bladder pocket is narrow, finding 1l ones is easy, most of the 1.5l are for hip bags, so wide and short). The bladder pocket is an elastic  mesh, so the jersey itself doesn't flop when the bladder is empty. As you drink, the bladder collapses, and when it's full, it's concave, so the contact area is more limited than a backpack. Not super comfy, but the compromise is OK for me.

Indeed, in a "Great plains" setup, I understand the difficulty of stopping, and stopping without shade is not particularly enjoyable as well.

I do not have an answer, but your description makes me wonder whether your setup may be modified to minimize the issue.
How long is the drinking tube? Maybe it is too long and requires too much effort to sip water into the mouth. I use either a backpack with a bladder and tube, or bottles. With the hydration pack, the water is above my waist level, so there is  very little pressure differential to fight against. If I where to install a drinking tube to my bottles, that would be about 15 inches or 38 centimeters that I'd need to elevate water.
If this height difference was the cause of your issue, I'd would consider mounting bottles on the handlebars. I have seen professional athletes competing with bottles in the handlebar and fitted with drinking tubes, so there are ready-made solutions for that.
The second thing is "technique". Which muscles are you using to sip the water? I would think that most people use the tongue, jaw and cheeks to sip water into the mouth and then, just swallow. A two step process. Is it possible that you are sucking with your chest or something like that? Are you trying to get the water from the bottle into the stomach in one single step?
At what point during the rides are you drinking? I purposefully drink during the least effort parts of the ride, either before starting a big uphill or after reaching the top or a less inclined part of it. No matter if I'm using the hydration pack (MTB) or bottles (Touring, commuting or road rides). It is not necessary to stop, but definitely drink during the parts of the rides where you have control of your breathing.

I added a picture of my hydration setup to the question so you can see what I'm dealing with. The height difference (not length of tube) does require a lot more suction and I have to use a bite valve to keep the water from draining down between drinks. That's part of the problem and I'm learning that I need to make an effort to drink slower, smaller sips because of the higher suction needed. Moving the bottle to the handlebars is an excellent suggestion but I think the logistics will take some research. My setup combines 5 different products and the shopping was a ton of work.

@user66598, My father used to have a hydration pack bladder on a makeshift handlebar bag. All the materials where harvested from a hydration pack. The bladder comes with the hose and bite valve already attached. We cut an external pocket of the backpack and sewn a couple of straps and velcro in order to attach it to the handlebars. It was a successful modification, at least for my dad.

After seeing the added picture I think you could mount the same bottle under or even over the top tube. I currently have 3 bottle cages on a frame that only has provisions for one. Hose clamps and rubber strips from inner tubes allow me to install them pretty much anywhere on the bike, but there are also commercially available solutions for that.

Another good location could be on the seat post. I have certainly seen it done. There are  plenty of mounts that allow for dual "regular size" bottles, and I bet that there must be one that fits your bottle. I did a image search for "seat post bottle cage" and saw many interesting ideas.

That's three possible new locations for the bottle right there and I'd only have to move my ABC cage from the bottle mounts to clamps on the top tube or seat post. I'd rather not move the bottle but that would be better than switching to a backpack I think.

There are two questions that you have to ask yourself, and I guess, their answers will clearly show you how to solve your problem:
Why are you swallowing at all?
When I'm breathing through my mouth, the last thing that I do would be to swallow. There's simply no need to do so. The high air volume going through my my mouth gives me a rather dry mouth, not an excess amount of saliva that needs to be removed. So why do you feel the need to swallow in the first place?
The need of drinking is definitely not a reason for frequent swallowing, you don't need more drinking than a few large gulps every half an hour, or so.
Why are you swallowing air when you swallow?
Normal swallowing technique is to first remove the gases from your mouth, and then to swallow. This applies irrespective of whether you are swallowing saliva or drinking from a possibly bubble containing tube. In either case, the normal procedure is that you first use your tongue to reduce the size of your mouth cavity to fit exactly the amount of liquid within, and push the air out through the open airstream behind. Only once you have the pure liquid trapped with your tongue should you proceed to close the path up to your nose to swallow the liquid only.
If this is not a description of what you are doing, I'm afraid you will have to learn to swallow correctly. There is no need to allow any significant amount of air to go down into your stomach; if it does, you are using the wrong technique.
Now, I am not a doctor, I'm just trying to be helpful. You may need to visit a doctor to fix this issue, but maybe a little more awareness about how and why you swallow may allow you to fix the problem yourself. Hope this helps.

I don't swallow much either but yesterday it was hot and I was breathing hard and my mouth was so dry I couldn't swallow because there was hardly any saliva. I was trying not to drink while breathing like that but I couldn't tolerate the dry mouth. Taking little sips not to drink but just to wet the mouth seemed like a good solution but I need to experiment with that a bit more.

I'm told that "sucking air" like this is somewhat normal for people who race really hard, regardless of whether they use water bottles or a tube, and there are often riders who belch like crazy during races. Someone else told me they race and it's normal to only be able to drink at certain places on the course, where exertion is low and they can do it without swallowing air. So yes, this is a serious problem, but it seems to have a clear, non-medical cause.

@user66598 thats why a lolly or hard candy in the mouth can help, by encouraging saliva.

Clarify please :  are you trying to breathe air into your lungs at the same time as you're drinking water?
No-one on earth can do that - the esophagus has a "valve" between your lungs and stomach.  Pausing breathing while swallowing is normal.
Source: https://www.lybrate.com/topic/esophagus-image
See how the paths between the mouth/stomach and mouth/lungs cross over in the same throat cavity and then fork off to the lungs via the trachea or the stomach via the esophagus.

On the other hand if you're mixing air with your water in your mouth, then swallowing that into your stomach mixed together sounds like a different matter.   Kind of like drinking a soft-drink/soda with carbonation.
Try:

Different technique - change things until improvement.  Perhaps sit up to drink, or try raising your bottle/bidon higher.
Handing - Try holding the bottle in your other hand to drink.
Timing - avoid drinking when you're pushing hard.  On a flat empty piece of road/track, take 10-20 seconds of soft pedalling, to let your heart rate drop.   Then try drinking.
Different bottle - could be the style of bottle allows water and air to be sucked into your mouth at the same time.
Suck vs squirt - Perhaps your mouth isn't forming an airtight seal around the spout, or try squirting from a distance and not touching the bottle.
Squeeze the bottle while drinking - this should pressurise the water and push it into your mouth

You've also mentioned a hydration pack.  Many of these suggestions apply, but also try cinching the straps to be shorter and make the pack ride higher.  Sucking up against gravity could be a cause too.
Perhaps a different liquid might help - add electrolytes or flavouring to your water, to fool your brain into doing something different.   A slightly thicker fluid like a Gel might provide some hydration.
Consider sucking on a lozenge or hard lolly/sweet/confectionary while riding.  This will encourage production of saliva in the mouth.  Personally I like hard-frozen squares of chocolate for the sugar kick as well.

Last resort is to take this problem to a medical professional who can see it in action in person and advise.

I've been paying more attention and, over the last few days but especially this morning, when I pull water into my mouth and then swallow, I feel like I'm swallowing the water over a bubble of air. As if there's air in the back of my mouth that the water has to go over before it goes down. That's EXACTLY what your picture shows! I think my problem is getting the water from my mouth past the UES without mixing it with air in my mouth or in between.

I'm definitely not trying to breath and drink at the same time, it just works out that sometimes I'm breathing so fast that I can't swallow fast enough to do it entirely between breaths and I end up swallowing air.

Some endurance racers have problems related to the foods they eat right before and during races. They debate which flavor tablets and/or gels are the cause. I drink plain, refrigerated water and at this point I'm hesitant to make a change that could make the problem worse. Hard candy sounds like a great solution for dry mouth when I'm breathing hard and don't want to drink water.

@user66598 I get it now - you're not trying to breathe while drinking, your lizard-brain is demanding air because you're working hard and need it NOW and overriding other things.

@user66598 dumb idea - can you pressurise your bottle by squeezing it?  That would push water up and into your mouth rather than having to suck.   Requires a sealed bottle and a pickup tube that goes right to the bottom of the bottle.

Squeezing the bottle is a good idea but not with a metal bottle. I'd have to get a different bottle. I have a few 2L ones but none are flexible.

@user66598 okay - how about blowing air into the bottle via the straw, to pressurise the inside?   Might be hard to control and get the right amount.... could be messy

the cap of the tube adapter kit has a vacuum relief valve that lets air in. It's silicone rubber and pops out for cleaning. Blowing into the tube make a bubbling noise and a hissing/squealing noise as air comes out the top, probably from that valve. The good news is that doing that confirmed for me that the quick connect between the two tubes is airtight. I recognized that as a possible mode of failure this morning.

Based on the photo, you're having to use suction to lift water from the bottle up a metre or so.
During this time you'll need to breathe through your nose, and generate suck with the mouth and specifically the tongue.  Since there's only so much space in the mouth, you're running out of space but releasing the vaccuum will allow the water to drop back in to the bottle.
I bet you're having to generate lift for the water by using your lungs, and the first water through is making it into the airstream.
ANSWER:  Shorten your straw to about 10cm, and lift the bottle higher, closer to your face to drink.
You might get away with the bottle at the height of your handlebars - a stem or top-tube mounted bottle might be a workable solution.   Another option could be a time-trial style hydration bottle that is fixed.
You can also try putting the bottle in a backpack so it has more "working pressure" in the straw.   A hydration backpack might suit you more than a bottle, though be aware body heat warms the water and it can be unpleasant.

Product idea - a helmet with built-in bottle cages, like those baseball caps with beer can holders ?   (not serious)

I really don't want water on my back but moving my current setup to the top tube might help. It would mean mounting the cage with clamps instead of bolts but it might be easier than switching bottles or trying to get that huge bottle on the stem/bars.
